# mousemove on multiple div with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a mousemove on mutiple divs with the same class name but the mouse position ain't restart inside of each divs.

here is the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vb4d29wx/2/)

here is my code:

```
<body>
<div class="reference" id="landing-content" style="background-image: url(http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/galaxy-s/galaxy-s7/gear-360/images/gear-360_slide360_02.jpg);"><section class="slider"></section></div>
<div class="reference" id="landing-content" style="background-image: url(http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/galaxy-s/galaxy-s7/gear-360/images/gear-360_slide360_01.jpg);"><section class="slider"></section></div>
<div class="reference" id="landing-content3"><section class="slider"></section></div>
<div class="reference" id="landing-content4"><section class="slider"></section></div>
<div class="reference" id="landing-content5"><section class="slider"></section></div>
<div class="reference" id="landing-content6"><section class="slider"></section></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>


$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.reference').mousemove(function(e){
  var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 1.15;
  var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 1.15;
  $(this).css('background-position', x + 'px ' + y + 'px');
  $(this).css('transition', 'background-position 1.5s ease-out');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `.reference` element with another element. And set it's position to `relative`. Also use `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` instead of `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`.Then the issue you are having will be resolved.

Working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.reference').mousemove(function(e) {
    var x = -(e.offsetX + this.offsetLeft) / 1.15;
    var y = -(e.offsetY + this.offsetTop) / 1.15;
    $(this).css('background-position', x + 'px ' + y + 'px');
    $(this).css('transition', 'background-position 1.5s ease-out');
  });
});
```

```css
.sliderBlock {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#landing-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  background-size: 190% 190%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-height: 500px;
}

#landing-content3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(http://virtualtourpro.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Kitchen-Dining-360.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  background-size: 190% 190%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-height: 500px;
}

#landing-content4 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(https://www.starkwoodmediagroup.com/assets/img/panorama/360-image.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  background-size: 190% 190%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-height: 500px;
}

#landing-content5 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(http://www.radschlag.at/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Panorama-2.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  background-size: 190% 190%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-height: 500px;
}

#landing-content6 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(http://www.easypano.com/gallery/panoweaver/201112021732/panoramamic.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  background-size: 190% 190%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.slider {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 100%;
  max-width: 1002px;
}
```

```html
<title>Parallax</title>

<body>
  <div class="sliderBlock">
    <div class="reference" id="landing-content" style="background-image: url(http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/galaxy-s/galaxy-s7/gear-360/images/gear-360_slide360_02.jpg);">
      <section class="slider"></section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sliderBlock">
    <div class="reference" id="landing-content" style="background-image: url(http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/galaxy-s/galaxy-s7/gear-360/images/gear-360_slide360_01.jpg);">
      <section class="slider"></section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sliderBlock">
    <div class="reference" id="landing-content3">
      <section class="slider"></section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sliderBlock">
    <div class="reference" id="landing-content4">
      <section class="slider"></section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sliderBlock">
    <div class="reference" id="landing-content5">
      <section class="slider"></section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sliderBlock">
    <div class="reference" id="landing-content6">
      <section class="slider"></section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/3muby46y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `backgroud-position` should be relative for each `.reference`. First one works fine because its maximum `-500px`. So second one will have `-1000px` and so on. You could do this:

```
 var x = -(Math.abs(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft)) / 1.15;
 var y = -(Math.abs(e.pageY - this.offsetTop)) / 1.15;
```

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.reference').mousemove(function(e){

    var x = -(Math.abs(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft)) / 1.15;
    var y = -(Math.abs(e.pageY - this.offsetTop)) / 1.15;
    $(this).css('background-position', x + 'px ' + y + 'px');
    $(this).css('transition', 'background-position 1.5s ease-out');

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your math on the `var x` and `var y` are wrong. Your deviding by `1.15` as you get lower on the e.pageY wil get bigger and your result wil get bigger and bigger.

without the deviding it works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.reference').each(function(){
  $(this).mousemove(function(e){
  var x = -e.pageX + this.offsetLeft;
  var y = -e.pageY + this.offsetTop;
    console.log(e.pageX);
     console.log(e.pageY);
    $(this).css('background-position', x + 'px ' + y + 'px');
    $(this).css('transition', 'background-position 1.5s ease-out');
  });
  });
});
```

so conclusion: Use other math for x and y.